# universal Image loader loading low quality image first

Tags: android

I'm doing the following to load a low quality image followed by the high quality one from the SD

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 16;
        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUrl, options);
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);                                 
        imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + imageUrl, image);
 }
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Please note that loading a low quality image first is a must, I tried many other alternative and none seems to work as smooth as the above.

Comment: Do you mean, the low quality image and the high quality are the same (just different quality)?

Comment: Yes the image is the same one, incremental loading if that makes sense.

Comment: [Interlacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_%28bitmaps%29) is probably what you are looking for. Photoshop has an "export to interlaced png" option for example. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is known as [interlacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_%28bitmaps%29). This means that when you try to load an image, it will load skipping a few pixels, multiple times, in order to present the viewer with the overall  shape as fast as possible.

In order to use this, you must encode your image to support interlacing. If you are using GIMP or Adobe Photoshop, it has the feature built-in to export interlaced images (PNG mostly).

#### Disclaimer

It is arguable that PNG or GIF interlacing should not be used because the significant change as the image continues loading. Some people don't agree on this. This choice is entirely yours.